# Scroll to specific element in overflowing div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a `div` with overflow that acts like a list (since a real "select" is a pain in the arse when customizing and keeping it that way in all browsers).

The Problem is, the list is long and I would like that when the page loads the "selected" element of the list would be more or less in the middle of the `div`, something like putting `selected=selected` to a `option` in a `select`.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jd7cP/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you mean? Inside your `#offertable` in css, add `text-align: left;`.The `text` will be more or less in the middle of the `div`

Comment: It's not a style problem... I was just trying to "auto-scroll-down" to the middle of the `div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to take the scroll to the middle, perhaps you could try this js:

```
 document.getElementById('wraptable').scrollTop = document.getElementById('wraptable').scrollHeight / 2;
```

It takes the scroll of the `#wraptable` to the middle.

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jd7cP/7/)**

Comment: This works PERFECT in the index page. But on the other pages I get in console the error `"TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null base.js:7"`. I'm guessing that is because the "wraptable" doesn't exist anywhereelse and the script tries to run it everywhere I go. Any way to go around it?

Comment: do you still have the #wraptable on other pages?

Comment: No. It's only on the index.
I tried to put the js code in a function that I called from the div with `onload="gotoSelected();"` but it doesn't work. No errors in console, nothing...

Comment: OK. I fixed it. I added the script line right after the DIV line in html and now it loades where it has to and when it has to. `<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('wraptable').scrollTop = document.getElementById('wraptable').scrollHeight / 2;</script>`. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an anchor :

1. give a specific id to one of your list items (example: "anchor")
2. when you link to this page, add the hashtag `#anchor` to the url and you list will be scolled to the list item with corresponding id.

Example url : `www.yourpage.com/list` should become `www.yourpage.com/list#anchor`

This **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/jd7cP/5/show/#anchor)** will show you.

```
<li id="anchor"><span>12 years</span> ... </li>

<a href="#anchor">anchor link</a>
```

[editable fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/jd7cP/2/)

Comment: You can also call 
window.location.href = '#anchor';
This will directly take you to that specific page. Just like calling the anchor tag.

Comment: The block is in the main `index`, and I can't/don't know how to keep always the "/#anchor" on the address bar, since it's changes dinamically "?location=.." etc.
I tried the `onLoad="window.location.href='#anchor';"` and it doesn't work... :/

Comment: @user3529213 did you manage with the anchor? I added some more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery you can make the "select" container to scroll to a specific element. In this case, I add a **.select** class to a random **li** just to show how it works.

Then, you can do the scroll on the **#wraptable** container by the number of pixels the **.selected** element is according to its parent.

```
$(function(){   
    var offsetSelectedElement = $(".selected").position().top;
    $("#wraptable").scrollTop(offsetSelectedElement);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jd7cP/6/)

**EDIT:**

To add jQuery simple add the library in the **head** section of your page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    ...
 </html>
```

If you don't want to use jQuery though, you still can achieve the same result through pure javascript, but it's more code:

```
var offsetSelectedElement = document.getElementsByClassName("selectedItem")[0];
var wrappable = document.getElementById("wraptable");
wrappable.scrollTop =  offsetSelectedElement.offsetTop;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jd7cP/11/)

Comment: That is awesome. Only problem is I don't know how to use jQuery. I tried adding this code in my base.js but something tell's me it's not the way to do it... The solution is perfect :(